# git stash merge conflict

Tags: git, github, merge

so I have 2 branches **master** and **feature-example**. I have a code change to **master** which I don't want to push to the repository. There's a commit to **feature-example** which I want to pull, So I did

```
git stash
git pull
```

and then

```
git checkout feature-example
```

now I made some changes to **feature-example** branch which I don't want to push, I want to checkout to **master** branch. so I am trying to do

```
git stash pop
```

It gives me conflict. And when I am trying to do

```
git checkout master
```

It says,

> app/assets/javascripts/abc.js: needs merge
>   error: you need to resolve your current index first

So I do not want my changes on **feature-example** to be pushed, I want it to be the old commit and I want to checkout to **master** branch.

PS: I do not want any commit to be made on the repo, not even the merge one.

Pretty weirdly asked but any help on this?

Comment: I hope your branches aren't actually called `master` and `master1`. That's very confusing.

Comment: they are not, updated the question

Comment: You need to give information about your current branch when you are running those commands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discard changes in a specific file you can use `git checkout -- <file>`:

I think this would solve your problem:

```
git checkout -- abc.js
```

Or you can resolve the conflict, commit the changes and reset head afterwards. The last commit will be removed:

```
A-B-C
    ^
  feature-example

git reset --hard HEAD~1

A-B
  ^
  feature-example
```